# \if and \fi inside different \def macros

Tags: conditionals, expansion, external-files

Recently I failed to solve specific task in LaTeX. I wanted to make document with several sections, each divided on several subsections. Each section I had placed to separate files, and used `\input` for them in the main file. So my `main.tex` file was rather short.
Then I tried to use set of following constructions:

```
\def\removesubsectionstext{\let\printsubsectionstext\iffalse\let\finalizeprinttext\fi}
\def\insertsubsectionstext{\let\printsubsectionstext\iftrue\let\finalizeprinttext\fi}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\finalizeprinttext%
\@startsection{section}{1}%
{0pt}{1.5ex plus .5ex minus .1ex}{0.8ex plus .1ex}%
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}%
\printsubsectionstext}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\finalizeprinttext%
\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
{0pt}{1.5ex plus .5ex minus .1ex}{0.8ex plus .1ex}
{\normalfont\bfseries}%
\printsubsectionstext}
\makeatother
```

By using this definitions and redefinitions I was hoping to hide texts inside some of the chapters, with contents elements remaining visible. I thought it was possible by this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,caption2}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-all,pst-3dplot,pst-optic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\insertsubsectionstext
\printsubsectionstext
\tableofcontents
\break
\input{chapter1}
\break
\removesubsectionstext
\input{chapter2}
\finalizeprinttext
\end{document}
```

Here I had expected to hide text from chapter2 and to see text from chapter1. But this is not working. I suspect it is impossible to use `\if` in one `\def` macro, and to close it with `\fi` in another. Is there workaround that will solve my problem?
I know, that I can manually insert in my text `\finalizeprinttext` and `\printsubsectionstext` near every `\section` and \subsection command, and that solved my problem partially. It is against automatic errors control. There is always opportunity to forget to insert `\finalizeprinttext` and `\printsubsectionstext` near new sections and subsections.

Comment: Rather than using `\iffalse` and `\iftrue` use `\newif` to define your own booleans. For example, `\newif\ifPrinting` which is set with `\Printingtrue` and `\Printingfalse`. In the include files you can then write `\ifPrinting....\fi.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: You are forgetting that TeX doesn't expand macros when it's skipping code, so you never see the `\fi` inside _e.g._ `\section`. It is possible to do line-by-line parsing to allow the type of skip behaviour you want, but it's tricky (see `beamer` for a possible approach).